# Why does this simple test of RequireJS define() does not work?

Tags: requirejs

I run:

```
define(
  function() {
    console.log('test');
    return null;
  }
);
```

No deps means it should queue and execute the callback and I would have to see `test` in the console. But no, I don't. What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set in your script tag an attribute referencing your js file.

```
<script data-main="yourjsfile.js" src="require.js"></script>
```

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected token return

Comment: Do you have the `data-main` attribute set in your script tag? eg `<script data-main="js/youjsfile.js" src="require.js"></script>`
Again your declaration was correct. I have updated my answer.

Comment: It should work without dependencies, per their docs http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#deffunc - so no, I don't add any tags because I don't actually define dependencies.

Comment: Yeah, I think it should. So how are you loading require js?

Comment: Then you need the `data-main` attribute in there referencing the js file where your function definition is. This should work.

Comment: Found the problem: 
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#mismatch -- basically I can't use anonymous define() function calls in a bootstrapped file. I can only in a file loaded using define(). In other words it works when I declare at least 1 dependency. So instead of boostrapping the main module I define() it.